# Zipwise.com Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, api, ssl, httpwebrequest, tls1.2

I'm running into an issue with my application. When trying to use ZipWise.com's api to get some zip codes I get the error "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." I did not make any changes to the program, and it all of a sudden stopped allowing me to use their API. I tried adding this to the beginning of my code before the request is created:

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

I disabled TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1,  SSL 2.0, and SSL 3.0 on the server (and rebooted). I'm able to open the url in a browser without issue. I verified on SSL Labs that they are using TLS 1.2.

When I run this on my development PC, it executes without issue and returns a bunch of zip codes. When I try to run it on the server, it fails and gives me that error.

Here is some sample code I used in a Windows forms application that produces the same error:

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;

        string url = "https://zipwise.com/webservices/radius.php?key=**********&zip=90210&radius=50";

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
        request.Method = "POST";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//exception occurs here

        StreamReader input = null;
        XDocument doc = null;

        if (response.StatusCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            input = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            doc = XDocument.Parse(input.ReadToEnd());
        }

        response.Close();
        request.ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup(request.ConnectionGroupName);

        if (input != null)
        {
            input.Close();

            var tempZips = (from z in doc.Descendants("result") select z.Descendants("zip").Single().Value).ToList();
            finalZips.AddRange(tempZips);

            foreach(string s in finalZips)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(s);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** The application is running on .NET 4.6, The SSL Cert on the server is still valid.

Comment: Did version of Net change or code get recompiled?  Is Certificate still valid?

Comment: Forgot to mention that, I'm using .NET 4.6 and yep the cert is still good.

Comment: People had issues when Net changed with the encryption using certificates.  I thought is was 4.7 but may be 4.6 also.  I'm suspecting that new Net is defaulting to 64 bit while old code used 32 bit.  Have not gotten any response indicating how to fix issue.